# Vue router not working when deployed to a server

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a vue application composed of 3 components. App, Home and View. I am using vite.
In App I have only a router viewer:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

In Home and View I have two buttons inside the header that moves between them.

```
<div class="header-buttons">
   <router-link to="/" class="header-button">Home</router-link>
   <router-link to="/view" class="header-button">View</router-link>
</div>
```

My router coniguration looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'; 
import App from './App.vue';
import Home from './Home.vue';
import View from './View.vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'; 

import './assets/main.css'

const app = createApp(App); 

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/view', component: View },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

app.use(router); 

app.mount('#app');
```

When I run this application locally I can freely move between the pages.
Next I deploy the app to a server. Application is prepared for production, dockerized and deployed to a kubernetes cluster.
This is the Dockerfile for this app:

```
FROM node:14 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Package.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

The app is running behind nginx with the default config, I did not change anything:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm
}
```

}

I can access the app but the buttons stop working. I am not getting any errors in the browser or anything, there is no response so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: So you click the buttons and what, _nothing_ happens? The URL doesn't change in the location bar? There's no errors in the browser console?

Comment: Exactly that. Nothing in the console, URL doesn't change, absolutely nothing happens. It works only on localhost

Comment: Any chance you can link to the live site?

Comment: sorry, it's for a cilent  and also behind a firewall so I cannot do that

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer then. Try using a different browser, disable extensions, use private / incognito mode, etc. Inspect the link elements, they should be regular `<a>` tags with the expected `href` attribute values. Make sure you're not [filtering out errors](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#filter) in your browser console

Comment: But in theory it should work once it's been dockerized and deployed, correct? Or perhaps each path requires a separate ingress in kubernetes?

Comment: Yes, it should just work. It seems unlikely that ingress would be an issue but you could always add more detail to your question

Comment: We need more context here. Are you using vue-cli or vite ? is there any error in the browser console ?

Comment: I am using vite. I am not getting any errors in the browser. I have tested this app in edge, chrome and firefox. Nothing is coming up. When running it locally it runs fine, it's only after I build it for production, dockerize and deploy to kubernetes that the buttons stop working

Comment: You may also check the package.json. make sure the library is in dependencies, not in devDependencies

Comment: Dude, Please tell us more about the server you've deployed on. Is there any nginx or apache http server on the go? Does any configurations exists ?

Comment: I think this is not a vue problem, this should be an nginx or kubernetes problem

Comment: I added some more details in my initial post. There is an nginx running the app. I will try to add nginx config as well.

Comment: Have you tried running the dockerised version locally? Can you reproduce the issue that way? FYI you're missing the required URL rewriting to support HTML5 history mode (but note this shouldn't prevent you navigating by clicking links). See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#nginx

Comment: could you please try to build and deploy without docker? So we can identify if it is docker problem.